# Typescript infer object keys for function based on properties in the same object

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Edit: Re-written the question to be more clear and added some additional examples.

I want to create one big object (this is a requirement of the underlying system) and I'd like to model one relationship between two elements of that object as a TypeScript interface/type that is automatically inferred by the TypeScript engine.

My object looks like this:

```js
{
  selection: {
    name: "",
    email: ""
  },
  handler: (values) => {
    // Do something
  }
}
```

What I'd like is to define a type such that the keys defined in `selection` object (`name` and `email` in this example, but could be many more) are inferred as keys on the `values` object.

E.g.:

```js
{
  selection: {
    name: "",
    email: ""
  },
  handler: (values) => {
    values.name // Valid
    values.email // Valid
    values.foobar // Not valid
  }
}

// or

{
  selection: {{
    name: "",
    email: ""
    address: "",
    role: ""
  },
  handler: (values) => {
    values.name // Valid
    values.email // Valid
    values.address // Valid
    values.role // Valid
    values.foobar // Not valid
  }
}
```

Using this type:

```js
interface HandlerObject<TSelection extends { [key: string]: string }> {
  selection: TSelection
  handler?: (selection: { [key in keyof TSelection]: any }) => any
}
```

I am able to type the object as long as I explicitly set the generic `TSelection` first:

```js
interface Selection {
  name: string
  email: string
}

const obj: HandlerObject<Selection> = {
  selection: {
    name: "",
    email: ""
  },
  handler: (values) => {
    values.name // Valid
    values.email // Valid
    values.foobar // Not valid
  }
}
```

To me, however, it *seems* like TypeScript should be able to infer `TSelection` itself based on what I type in the `selection` property. Though I may be wrong of course. I'm theorizing that I should be able to do this:

```
const obj: InferredHandlerObject = {
  selection: {
    name: "",
    email: ""
  },
  handler: (values) => {
    values.name // Valid
    values.email // Valid
    values.foobar // Not valid
  }
}
```

and still get proper type inference for `name` and `email` in some way. Is this possible or am I required to type out the selection explicitly?

---

**Original question**

```js
// SomeType is just a placeholder. This is where I want the proper type to go.
const obj: AType = {
  selection: {
    name: "something", // The value here is irrelevant. The key is important
    email: "something elese" // The value here is irrelevant. The key is important
  },
  handler: (selection) => {
    selection.name // selection only contains keys from the selection object defined above
  }
}
```

Is there a way to type this using Typescript in such a way that the selection `argument` always contains the same keys as those defined in the `selection` property? The values of the keys in the argument should also not be the same.

I've tried this:

```js
interface HandlerObject<TSelection extends { [key: string]: string }> {
    selection: TSelection
    handler?: (selection: { [key in keyof TSelection]: any }) => any
}
```

but it requires me to specify the generic explicitly.

[image]

I'd like it to infer `TSelection` based on the `selection` property automatically.

Comment: What's the definition of `SomeType`?

Comment: It's just a placeholder for where the proper type should go. I've updated the question with a clarification.

Comment: Hmmm, that's a problem. If you don't have a type for `obj`, you can't refer to it in the object initializer to get the type information. You get *"'obj' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation and is referenced directly or indirectly in its own initializer.(7022)"*

Comment: Here's what that looks like: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBCBGArGBeGBvAUDGECmANnsFAJbgBcG2OMYAhgLZ5UBE+RJAdA86wDQ0ceRvVIE2HYlC4ixBVjQC+gnAAt6YACZEATlQAUUkuTBUoATwAOeEADM4SANrtC006wC6ASlQA+alpcNxNwHiY8ZUwlIA

Answer (score 1):

You've said `SomeType` is a "placeholder for where the property type should go." If `obj` is a one-off, you don't need a type on it at all; TypeScript will infer it from the object initializer. But we'll need to split it up a bit because otherwise you're trying to refer back to it from its own initializer, and TypeScript won't let you do that. You get *"'obj' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation and is referenced directly or indirectly in its own initializer.(7022)"* ([playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBCBGArGBeGBvAUDGECmANnsFAJbgBcG2OMYAhgLZ5UBE+RJAdA86wDQ0ceRvVIE2HYlC4ixBVjQC+gnAAt6YACZEATlQAUUkuTBUoATwAOeEADM4SANrtC006wC6ASlQA+alpcNxNwHiY8ZUwlIA)).

Here's how we can do it using `typeof` in the type declaration, by separating it a bit:

```
const initialSelection = {
    name: "select.name",
    email: "select.email"
};
const obj = {
    selection: initialSelection,
    handler: (selection: typeof initialSelection) => {
        selection.name // This works
    }
};
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAlmOU4EMA2BlApmrxngwC8MA3gFAxUxgoC2WAXDAEQQ55QB0tDLANJWpY6KOGmZsO+LiLFoW5AL4BucqEiwQAIwBWxMkKrtc+OOGYIkqTNIJhB1GAAsUYACa4ATswAUJznMwZigATwAHLBAAM3hEZHRsU3sASmIAPkMnJwCzcB56LBgAemKYABVnOAgYAHcQLwBrCCMYJWUVIA)

If you want to avoid having `initialSelection` in that scope, you can wrap this in a function:

```
const obj = (() => {
    const initialSelection = {
        name: "select.name",
        email: "select.email"
    };
    return {
        selection: initialSelection,
        handler: (selection: typeof initialSelection) => {
            selection.name // This works
        }
    };
});
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBCBGArGBeGAKdBKVA+GA3gFAykyiSwCWYVUVAhgDYDKApk28PeKoSWUFgGAWzYAuGACIIHLlAB0wsVIA0AwaTYiGVJpJlzuC7bqZSNMAL4BuSwCc2UAK72w-TWVmduVcJJo6RlYjHjB1T1IACwYwABNOe0l0b3k-MEkoAE8ABzYQADMYQPpmdh8wnBR8YkjNVN9wJVE2GAB6NpgAFSiqCBgAdxB7AGsIS0ErS1siKyw7IA)

Comment: This is close to what I want, but I was hoping that TypeScript could infer the type of another object property directly avoiding the need for an anonymous function or explicit definitions separate from the actual object.

Comment: @Thomas - Fairly sure you can't (i was sorry to see). The error from TypeScript when you try is fairly clear (which I was pleased to see). :-)

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. Thanks for helping me look into it.

Answer (score 1):

If you insist to have everything in one object, you'll need to define `SomeType` like this:

```
interface SomeType {
  selection: {
    name: string;
    email: string;
  },
  handler: (selection: SomeType['selection']) => void;
}

const obj: SomeType = {
  selection: {
    name: "select.name",
    email: "select.email"
  },
  handler: (param) => {
    param.name;
    param.email;
  }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMoHsC2EAqBPABxQG8AoZZAZwgBsIExh0QAuZMiikObNysKKADmAbnKcImOMBp8BwsRQC+AGnEALOCAAmdKGwAU1Ogyas0WXIQgBtAOTH6jZnYC6ASmQBeAHzIAbujA2mJKpKQIzPzI6ABGAFZsGNj4RN7s4o6mzGwcnNy8yABEWWAAdAUQRWqcyJLSssWlZfUyReKqGlq60IYEcFA8nr4Ztf2DmBU8EIqc4zwtUjKzYUpAA)

Comment: Ideally I'd like to keep it within a single object because that is how the framework I'm working with operates (Sanity.io). I know I can type it like this or using multiple types, but I was hoping it would be possible to infer it directly. TypeScript should already have all the necessary data.

Comment: Just to be clear. I don't at all mind defining a type, but I'd like to avoid having to define new types for the selection property whenever I use it.

Comment: @Thomas don't think this is possible, but you can you use generics like [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMoHsC2EAqBPABwgB4cA+ZAbwChlkBnCAGwgTGHRAC5kdbkAFnBAATFlB4AKRizYduvAJTIAvBQBu6YCIDc1AL7VqCTvTDJ0AIwBWPDNnxFilZCDjYeZqKADmO5BCYcMBMnmDeIH7I+hQqVPwyrOycPDR0dG4eyABEiWwAdJkQ2QA0-HSBwaE5eWD5lSHZ-PpldEKi4lIEcFDuymrx6cjdvZiF7hB6QyPu9UEhU9EGQA).

Comment: Also, this *is* one object, an interface is not an object.

Comment: I know I can use generics, but that still requires me to re-define properties that IMHO *should* be inferrable by TypeScript itself. For now I'll simply stick to "any" as it quickly becomes annoying to type the entries twice. Thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: @Thomas The thing is, if typescript lets you reference the object in itself without previously typing it, then how can it  know which type it is? Sometimes some effort has to be made in order to have safe typing, but I'd still take that over using `any` anyday.

Comment: Usually I would absolutely agree @Mike, but in my case having to explicitly write types here would basically double the amount of code needed. The type would also never be used outside the specific instance which makes it far less useful. Typescript is a recommendation, not a requirement and for this specific case I'm happy to trim it out.

Comment: regarding how TypeScript would know the type. TypeScript can easily infer the object type for static objects directly. As this is also a static object I don't see why it should be more difficult to infer this here. Splitting the object in two would make it trivial. Something like `keyof this["selection"]` to get the type would be sufficient.

Comment: In short all of this has to do with readability vs strong typing. I'm usually a stickler for strong types, but in this case it would mean diverging from every example the underlying framework uses even though every object is static anyway. This makes it harder for new devs to understand and requires having to juggle more pieces of code at once. This is by no means a huge issue and we may strongly type it at some point. I was more interested in if it was possible as my initial gut reaction was that it *should* be possible.

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure what you are after but I'd assume you know what will go into "selection" and it may vary case by case and you'd like to ensure the handler uses only existing properties.

```
interface SomeType<T> {
    selection: T,
    handler: (selection: T) => void
}

type User {
    name: string;
    email: string;
}


const obj: SomeType<User> = {
  selection: {
    name: "select.name",
    email: "select.email"
  },
  handler: (selection) => {
    selection.name // selection only contains keys from the selection object defined above
  }
}
```

Comment: I've updated the question to hopefully make things more clear. I'm trying to get TypeScript to do the heavy lifting of inferring the keys of T for me since I'm explicitly defining them within the object itself.

Answer (score 0):

For whatever reason, generic type inference operates differently on functions than on types.

Here's the solution:

```
function isObj<O>(obj: { selection: O; handler: (selection: { [key in keyof O]: any }) => any }) {
  return obj;
}

const obj = isObj({
  selection: {
    name: '',
    email: '',
  },
  handler(values) {
    values.name; // Valid
    values.email; // Valid
    values.foobar; // Not valid
  },
});
obj;
```